# BitmapFactory.decodeResource returning null on Tablet device

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following code that loads an image to display in an image view.  decodeResource returns an image when I use Galaxy S6 as a test device. However, it returns null for the same image when a test device is Galaxy Tab. I noticed that there is 'v24' right next to my image resource name. I just dragged and dropped my image from Finder to Drawable. Could it be because of that?

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()


    val image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.village)

}
```

Comment: Galaxy s6 has android 6.0.1 installed which is api 23, so yes, probably v24 is your problem

Comment: On s6, it loads just fine. It's Galaxy Tab that's having problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v24 qualifier means that that drawable is available only for -v24 api and above, you can check api versions [here](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers). If you don't have that drawable in the "unversioned" drawable folder BitmapFactory will decode a null drawable.
Create your drawable also for lower apis, you can use a useful IntelliJ plugin if your want, called [DrawableImporter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer)

Comment: Happy to hear that :)

Comment: I was under impression that "drawable" directory shows in Android Studio is unversion directory since there's no indication of version number in directory name. I was confused to see v24 next to image name. When I use "Reveal in Finder", that's when I realize my image is actually inside drawable-v24 directory. I moved the image to unversioned directory and it works as expected. Thanks for your help!